# Define Frontpage in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

how can I define a custom page as frontpage in Silverstripe? So when the user opens www.example.com the page "Welcome" is displayed.

Is there a option where I can set a page as frontpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the page with URLSegment 'home' that's always used as the homepage (which - unfortunately - isn't configurable yet).
so just change the URLSegment of your homepage to 'home' (but change the URLSegment of the existing homepage to something different first).

see f.i. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/1427

Comment: Thanks. Are things like this documented anywhere? I couldn't find a solution in the docs or via google

Comment: there is http://userhelp.silverstripe.org/ but it doesn't seem to mention the 'home' URLSegment, instead they're talking about a 'HomePage' page type, not sure about this one.